# How to get context from ActivityManager.RunningTaskInfo?

Tags: android, android-context

I want to get context from the below code.

I have not able to find the how to get activity so please help me in same.

**CODE :**

```
ActivityManager mActivityManager = (ActivityManager) getSystemService(Context.ACTIVITY_SERVICE);
List<ActivityManager.RunningTaskInfo> RunningTask = mActivityManager.getRunningTasks(1);
ActivityManager.RunningTaskInfo ar = RunningTask.get(0);
String activityOnTop=ar.topActivity.getClassName();
```

Thanks in Advance

Comment: I want to detect which activity is running in my application and i want to convert that activity which i get in "activityOnTop" want to convert into so I get do intent to one activity to another activity

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> How to get context from ActivityManager.RunningTaskInfo?

Call `createPackageContext` method for getting Context using top Activity package name:

```
ActivityManager.RunningTaskInfo ar = RunningTask.get(0);
String packageName = ar.topActivity.getPackageName();
Context otherAppContext=getApplicatoinContext().createPackageContext(packageName,
                                                   Context.CONTEXT_IGNORE_SECURITY);
```

Comment: @VatsalShah: first you told i'm not able to found context and now saying not able to find activity. which Activity you want to found?

Comment: Sorry it was my mistake.

Comment: @VatsalShah: your small mistake change the meaning of answer and question. ok let me know which acivity you want to get?

Comment: @VatsalShah:  which acivity you want to get?

Comment: I want acitivity name which come in "activityOnTop"

Comment: @VatsalShah: but you are getting Activity name here `String activityOnTop=ar.topActivity.getClassName();` ? then what  is issue?

Comment: I will get class name e.g. com.example.abc.Main I want to convert it into activity so I will get root view of that activity

Comment: @VatsalShah: Great!!! then you will get screen-shot from root-view right? not possible

Comment: Should I know the reason why its not possible ? I want to take screenshot of my app only. I don't want to write code on each and every activity

Comment: I don't want to use this thing in out of the application.

Comment: @VatsalShah: but i don't think it's possible so you can do it using Application class or writing code in one place then call it from every activity to set current Activity context for accessing rootview

Comment: @VatsalShah: also try this code `   ActivityManager mActivityManager = (ActivityManager) getSystemService(Context.ACTIVITY_SERVICE);
   List<ActivityManager.RunningTaskInfo> RunningTask = mActivityManager
     .getRunningTasks(1);
   ActivityManager.RunningTaskInfo ar = RunningTask.get(0);
   String activityOnTop = ar.topActivity.getClassName();
   Class<?> c2 = Class.forName(activityOnTop);

   Activity activity = (Activity) c2.newInstance();
   activity.getWindow().getDecorView().findViewById(android.R.id.content);` probably help

Comment: activity.getWindow().getDecorView().findViewById(android.R.id.content); - This will give nullpointerException

Comment: @VatsalShah that's why I'm saying probably not possible in way which you are currently using so try it using Application class

Comment: Typo here `getApplicatoinContext` => `getApplicationContext`